# SQL 2 counts or 2 sums when a date column is selected

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, count

I've been trying to figure this out, but can't get it right.

I want to select the ID, table S date, 2 different counts for the number of Type = 1 and Type = 2 where the date in table P is >= the max date from table S where note = J, and a date difference between the max table P date and the table S date.

Example table data:

```
Table S     
Date          ID    Note
2/26/2014   688606  J
2/14/2014   688606  J


Table P 
Date          ID    Type
7/10/2015   688606  1
7/9/2015    688606  1
7/8/2015    688606  1
7/7/2015    688606  2
1/2/2010    688606  1
1/1/2010    688606  2
```

Ideal result set:

```
S.Date      S.ID    P.MaxDate   P.T1Count   P.T2Count   P.DateDiff
2/26/2014   688606  7/10/2015       3            1         499
```

I've tried SUMs, but then I can't figure out how to incorporate the dates since SUM requires a group by and the dates are all unique.

I tried counts with a partition by the ID, but that makes the count include all data in table P rather than just those with dates >= table S.

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks,

Here's my go at it with only 1 count:

```
SELECT 
S.ID,
S.DATE as SDATE,
P.DATE as PDATE,
P.TYPE,
COUNT(P.DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY P.ID) as NBR_T1,
(P.DATE - S.DATE)as NBR_DATES
FROM
P
JOIN 
(
SELECT
DISTINCT(S.ID),
S.DATE,
S.NOTE 
FROM 
S
WHERE 
S.DATE = (SELECT MAX(SS.DATE)
FROM SS
WHERE SS.ID = S.ID
AND SS.NOTE = 'J')
AND S.ID = '688606'
) S ON P.ID = S.ID
WHERE
P.TYPE = '1' 
AND P.ID = '688606'
AND P.DATE >= S.DATE

ORDER BY 
P.DATE DESC
```

Comment: which database is this?  Please tag it.

Comment: Please provide what the example output you want the query to display.

Comment: Added example output & db (sqlserver)

Comment: You can use the DATEDIFF function, that can give you the difference in day, hours, exc...

Comment: Do your tables have primary keys?

Answer (score 0):

If you really only have 2 types then this solution will work.  If you have N types and you therefor want N columns that you'd need to use a `PivotTable`.

Hopefully this helps.

```
    USE SomeDB;

    CREATE TABLE S (dt DATETIME NOT NULL, sTableid INT NOT NULL);

    INSERT INTO S VALUES ('2/26/2014', 688606), ('2/14/2014', 688606);

    CREATE TABLE P (dt DATETIME NOT NULL, pTableid INT NOT NULL, typeID INT NOT NULL);

    INSERT INTO P VALUES 
    ('7/10/2015', 688606, 1),
    ('7/9/2015', 688606, 1),
    ('7/8/2015', 688606,  1),
    ('7/7/2015', 688606, 2),
    ('1/2/2010', 688606, 1),
    ('1/1/2010', 688606,  2);

    WITH tmp AS (
    SELECT pTableid, p.typeID, MAX(dt) maxDate, COUNT(1) cnt
    FROM dbo.P
    GROUP BY pTableid, p.typeID
    )
SELECT s.dt, 
    s.sTableid, 
    (SELECT MAX(maxDate) FROM tmp WHERE tmp.pTableid = s.sTableid) maxDateOfAnyType,
    (SELECT cnt FROM tmp WHERE tmp.pTableid = s.sTableid AND tmp.typeID = 1) t1Count,
    (SELECT cnt FROM tmp WHERE tmp.pTableid = s.sTableid AND tmp.typeID = 2) t2Count,
    DATEDIFF(DAY, s.dt, (SELECT MAX(maxDate) FROM tmp WHERE tmp.pTableid = s.sTableid)) daysBetween
FROM dbo.S s    

    DROP TABLE S;
    DROP TABLE P;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably easiest if you aggregate the data in `S` first—I like CTEs for this—and then apply the necessary aggregation to the corresponding data in `P`. Like so:

```
-- Sample data.
declare @s table ([Date] date, [ID] bigint, [Note] char(1));
insert @s values
    ('2014-02-26', 688606, 'J'),
    ('2014-02-14', 688606, 'J');

declare @p table ([Date] date, [ID] bigint, [Type] int);
insert @p values
    ('2015-07-10', 688606, 1),
    ('2015-07-09', 688606, 1),
    ('2015-07-08', 688606, 1),
    ('2015-07-07', 688606, 2),
    ('2010-01-02', 688606, 1),
    ('2010-01-01', 688606, 2);

-- Step 1: Aggregate and filter the records you want in @s.
with [GroupS] as
(
    select
        [S].[ID],
        [Date] = max([S].[Date])
    from
        @s [S]
    where
        [S].[Note] = 'J'
    group by
        [S].[ID]
)

-- Step 2: Aggregate the corresponding records in @p.
select
    [S.Date] = [GroupS].[Date],
    [S.ID] = [GroupS].[ID],
    [P.MaxDate] = max([P].[Date]),
    [P.T1Count] = sum(case [P].[Type] when 1 then 1 else 0 end),
    [P.T2Count] = sum(case [P].[Type] when 2 then 1 else 0 end),
    [P.DateDiff] = datediff(day, [GroupS].[Date], max([P].[Date]))
from
    [GroupS]
    inner join @p [P] on [GroupS].[ID] = [P].[ID]
where
    [GroupS].[Date] <= [P].[Date]
group by
    [GroupS].[Date],
    [GroupS].[ID];
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with just subqueries?  The with groups portion doesn't seem to be working.  I also don't have a good grasp on how your query is working since it is selecting s.date but table s isn't in the from or join section.

Comment: If you mean in place of the CTE, then yes, it's just a quick cut-and-paste: you take the query that's in the parentheses following the `WITH` and stick it in the `FROM` clause of the step 2 query. I'm not sure why you'd want to do this, though, unless you're using a version of SQL Server that pre-dates CTEs. You can read more on the topic [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx). Also, if there's a part of the query that's not working, you'll have to be specific about what's wrong.

Comment: To clarify one point you raised: step 2 _doesn't_ select `S.Date`, at least not directly. The expression `[S.Date] = [GroupS].[Date]` means exactly the same thing as `[GroupS].[Date] as [S.Date]`, so `S.Date` isn't an expression being evaluated, it's just a column alias. I like the former syntax better because all the column aliases end up left-aligned and they're easier for me to find that way, but it's purely a matter of taste.

Comment: Gotcha, I hadn't seen the "=" rather than "as" before.  It looks to be working by inserting the query from step 1 into the from section of step 2.  Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it... I assume you have table `S` and `P` already created and using SQL Server `2012+`.

```
Declare @MDate datetime
SELECT @MDate = MAX(SS.DATE) FROM S SS WHERE SS.NOTE = 'J'

Select S.Date, S.ID, Max(P.Date) as 'MaxDate', 
COUNT(IIF(convert(int,P.Type)=1, 1, NULL)) AS T1Count,
COUNT(IIF(convert(int,P.Type)=2, 1, NULL)) AS T2Count,
datediff(day, S.Date, Max(P.Date)) as 'DateDiff' from P 
inner join S on P.ID = S.ID and S.Date >= @MDate
and P.Date >= @MDate
group by S.Date, S.ID
```